# Open a xml after clicking button in odoo 10

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

How do we open a new xml form in odoo 10 ? I want to open `views/views.xml` after logging in the system.

My `LogIn_SignUp.xml`:

```
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="LogIn_form_view">
        <field name="name">Logging</field>
        <field name="model">studentmanagement.sinhvien</field>
        <field name="type">form</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Logging">
                <group>
                    <field name="LienLac"/>
                    <field name="MatKhau" type="password"/>
                    <button string="Log In" type="object" name="Log_In"/>
                </group>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

function "Log_In()" in python :
[image: (If account and password match a record in database, a new form is opened]

But it doesn't work: it not only does not change the page, but also inserts a row into the database `studentmanagement.sinhvien`! So I don't understand what happened!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `view_id` of the dictionary you are returning to the id of your view, that is `your_module_name.LogIn_form_view`

Comment: does it mean
'view_id' : 'studentmanagement.view.xml'
? I want it to show 'view.xml' after clicking the button

Comment: No. The view_id is not the xml file. The xml file can contain multiple views. The id is the id attribute of your record tag.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you need to decorate your method with `@api.model`
and then on your return `dict` values you need to change the `view_id` into something like this `view_id`: `self.env.ref("module_name.XML_ID").id`

`XML_ID` is an `id` defined in the xml
for example:
        `<record id="view_login_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name=""></field>
</record>`
so, the XML_ID must be `view_login_form`